# delete database entries if expired (based on date) using query builder

Tags: typeorm

I would like to delete all my invalidated json web tokens from the database that have expired already. I'm using TypeORM and I think I have to use the query builder for that.

My token entity has a column representing the time the token expires

```
  @Column()
  public expiresOn: Date;
```

I want to setup a cronjob deleting all expired tokens from the database. So what I currently have is

```
  @Interval(2000) // gets called every 2 seconds - for demo purposes
  public async handleInterval(): Promise<void> {
    const currentDate: Date = new Date();

    const deleteExpiredTokensQuery: SelectQueryBuilder<Token> = this.tokensRepository.createQueryBuilder('token');
    deleteExpiredTokensQuery.where('token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate });

    await deleteExpiredTokensQuery.delete();
  }
```

Unfortunately no token gets deleted, although the token expires on

```
1970-01-19 07:32:20.093
```

So how to fix my query? I think the plain Query would be

```
DELETE FROM tokens WHERE expiresOn < GETDATE()
```

---

**Update**

I thought I would have to create a delete query builder

```
const deleteExpiredTokensQuery: DeleteQueryBuilder<Token> = this.tokensRepository.createQueryBuilder('token');
```

but then I get this error

> Type 'SelectQueryBuilder' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'DeleteQueryBuilder': output, returning,
>   createDeleteExpression

Answer (score 1):

By calling `delete()` on `QueryBuilder` it only declares this query as a deletion. To execute the query you have to call `execute()`. See the [docs for delete](https://typeorm.io/#/delete-query-builder).

```ts
await this.tokensRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('token')
    .delete()
    .where('token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate })
    .execute();
```

About the second problem: You do not have to specify the type of the variable explicitly, since it get inferred automatically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. When I call your code `    await this.tokensRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('token')
      .delete()
      .where('token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate: new Date() })
      .execute();` I get the following error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "token"` When I add this `.from(Token)` I still get the error message

Comment: Try something like this: ```getRepository(Token).createQueryBuilder('token').delete().where('token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate }).execute();``` where `Token` is your entity object. Otherwise set the table entity with `.from(Token)` in your query like in the official docs.

Comment: hm sorry, unfortunately that didn't fix the error. I opened an issue here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5320